# Responsive design for a blocks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn how to create responsive design and actually have a few questions. First of all, can I move BLOCK2 under BLOCK4 in samller resolution? (my media queries have 736px max-width[image]

Here's css:

```
    div.block1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  ;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.right {
  margin-left: 200px;
  overflow: hidden
}
div.block2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.center {
  margin-right: 200px
}
div.block3 {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.block4 {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
```

And here's html:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="block1">
      block1
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="block2">
        block2
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <div class="block3">
          block3
        </div>
        <div class="block4">
          block4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does the HTML need to remain the same? In addition to that, the code provided does not recreate the image. Are you missing some code?

Comment: Easiest way is to use bootstrap.

Comment: Yes you may move, but it would be easier to ' display:none; ', the div with media query.

Comment: Jaunt, sorry? This code display the same, that at the picture. At the star there is just css for header and div.main {overflow: hidden}

Comment: Tanjir, bootstrap..I'm not sure

Comment: Shudhansh Shekhar, Ye, I know, but I need to display that block at the small reolution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/87/

**HTML**

```
<header>
    This is header
</header>
<div class="main">
    <div class="block block-1">
        <p>This is box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block block-2">
        <p>This is box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block block-3">
            <p>This is box 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block block-4">
            <p>This is box 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
    background: #004E52;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
}

.block-1, .block-2 {
    padding: 100px 20px;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.block-1 {
    order: 1;
}

.row {
    order: 2;
}

.block-2 {
    order: 4;
}

.row {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.block-3, .block-4 {
    padding: 35px 100px;
}
```

Comment: Made a mistake there but i fixed it.

Comment: Thank you a lot! But actually it doesn't move block when I resize window :(

Comment: Can you show how blocks should look like before and after resize?

Comment: They just need to stand under each other, as example: box3, under it box4 and then under theese 2 blocks will stay box2

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to reorder and recontainerize some of the elements.

```
<header>
</header>
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="main container">
<div id="block3"></div>
<div id="block4"></div>
</div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Then float on big screens and remove the float on small screens

```
body > div{
    float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:738px){
    body > div{
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank! I'll try it now